# Creating a tree with Breadth-First Search

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to generate a tree from string in which this tree is "coded" in Breadth-First Search way. My structures:

```
/* declaration for queue structure */
typedef struct node node;

/* queue structure for algorithms */
typedef struct queue {
  node *item;
  struct queue *nextItem;
} queue;

/* tree node */
typedef struct node {
  int value;
  int numOfChildren;    // to avoid the necessity of creating "dummy nodes" at the end of children array
  struct node **children;
} node;
```

Examples:

For input *"20."* there should be a tree:

```
20
```

For input *"20. 10 30 40 50."* there should be a tree:

```
    20
10 30 40 50
```

And for input *"20. 10 30 40 50. . 31 32. . 51 52."* there should be a tree:

```
        20
10   30   40   50
   31 32      51 52
```

So the tree is "coded" with numbers, spaces and dots. And I have a problem with trees generating. Here's my UNFINISHED *initTree(char *)* function:

```
void initTree(char *strTree) {
  queue *queueStart = NULL;
  queue *queueEnd = NULL;  // to speed up adding items to queue...
  queue *queuePointer = NULL;
  int numOfChildren = 0;
  while(*strTree != '\0') {
    if(*strTree == '.') {
      if(queueStart == queueEnd) {  // first dot
        if(ROOT == NULL)
          ROOT = queueStart->item;
      } else if(*(strTree-1) == ' ' && numOfChildren == 1) {
        queueStart = queueStart->nextItem;
      } else {  // queueStart != queueEnd && numOfChildren > 0
        queueStart->item->children = childrenConstructor(numOfChildren);
        queueStart->item->numOfChildren = numOfChildren;
        if(queueStart == queuePointer)
          queuePointer = queueStart->nextItem;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<numOfChildren; ++i) {
          queueStart->item->children[i] = nodeConstructor(queuePointer->item->value);
          queuePointer = queuePointer->nextItem;
        }
        // REMEMBER TO DELETE QUEUE ITEM
        // queue *tmp = queueStart;
        queueStart = queueStart->nextItem;
      }
      numOfChildren = 0;
    } else if(*strTree == ' ') {
      ++numOfChildren;
    } else {  // *strTree >= '0' && *strTree <= '9'
      if(queueStart == NULL) {
        queueStart = queueEnd = strToInt(&strTree);
        queuePointer = queueStart;
      } else {
        queueEnd->nextItem = strToInt(&strTree);
        queueEnd = queueEnd->nextItem;
      }
      if(numOfChildren == 1)
        queuePointer = queueEnd;
    }
    ++strTree;
  }
  // REMEMBER TO DELETE A QUEUE
}
```

So, what's the matter?
Well, when I'm trying to print that tree in simple way (only for testing purposes), with input *"20. 10 30 40 50. . 31 32. . 51 52."*, the second "level" of the tree is not "visible". As if children haven't been added to the tree.
Here's my print function:

```
void simpleRecursiveTreePrint(node *n) {
  if(n == NULL)
    return;
  printf("value %d (num of children: %d)\n", n->value, n->numOfChildren);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<n->numOfChildren; ++i)
    simpleRecursiveTreePrint(n->children[i]);
  return;
}
```

And output (for mentioned input):

```
value 20 (num of children: 4)
value 10 (num of children: 0)
value 30 (num of children: 0)
value 40 (num of children: 0)
value 50 (num of children: 0)
```

So, well, it looks like the nodes were lost... But in vscode, when I'm debbuging, nodes *31, 32, 51 and 52* are processed in function *initTree(char *)*. Hm, maybe there's a problem with pointers assignment? Or in allocating a memory? I really don't know... And I got headache from this coding :D

Anyone?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: So, maybe I found an answer. Problem was with line `queueStart->item->children[i] = nodeConstructor(queuePointer->item->value);` -- it should be `queueStart->item->children[i] = queuePointer->item;`.

Comment: Yeah... I was creating new node unnecessarily - instead of using existing one. A queue should be just a "cover". While planning, I thought it is important to save memory.